# Unable to redirect some output of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to create a python script to execute tests and saving the output to a file without printing to console.

The problem is that it appears that some of the output lines are not sent to its default stdout, but directly to the console instead.

For example, this is how I start the subprocess:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['php', 'bin/phpunit'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

After this line, I can simply redirect all of the stdout and stderr output to a file. This is working for almost every output of the command, including the test results. But I am still getting these lines directly on the console:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54044/devtools/browser/07a3f199-6bc5-4fbf-b7eb-a1684510b757

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54233/devtools/browser/0db8ac62-de3e-41de-b64e-50985dd861d8

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54233/devtools/browser/51434c77-9961-48ad-ba14-47c5a42bc211
```

Is there a way to avoid direct prints to console? Maybe I could run this command in a "virtual console" so the output goes to that "virtual console" instead of to the real one?

Comment: what do you run in test? It seems you runs some browser but it may run as separated process without redirecting outputs.

Comment: @furas I am running ChromeDriver to run tests on a simulated client.